# mod_expires vs new content?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm finishing to build a static site (with HTML, CSS and JS only), but I have a problem with the cache of the client-side browser.

Well, I'm working with an Apache server and to optimize the loading (according to suggestions from sites like GMetrix, Google Insight, etc) I added some code in my .htaccess file.

```
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml text/x-js text/js 
</IfModule>
```

The problem starts when I have to update the content of a particular page, but due to the cache stored by the browser, can't see the update unless the page is reloaded (F5).

**My question is**: I must remove these lines added in .htaccess or is there an automatic way to force new content display in the client browser?

I post updates every day on the index.html page, but with the browser storing cached users do not always see new content.

Can you suggest me a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: _“I post updates every day on the index.html page”_ – well then you should _not_ instruct browsers that resources of type `text/html` would expire after a month only …

Comment: Hi CBroe. Do you mean I should remove that line or change it for another one? Thanks!

Comment: Using an `Expires` header with a longer time value only makes sense for resource that _won’t_ change over that period of time. Your HTML documents do – so it _does not_ makes sense for them. So yes – remove it. (Or use a lower time value – one that you can live with, if perhaps your updates are not shown during it.)

Comment: Hey CBroe, sorry for delay. Man, you're a genius! I did what you said and it worked like a charm =) Thanks more one time man.